# How can Instagram Media Id's be compared?

Tags: instagram-api

Here is an example of an Instagram Media Id:
908991138574797936_536823746

If there were two of these ids and I wanted to find out which one was greater than the other how would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an arbitrary value they assign. I wouldn't assume anything about what a comparison between two of them means. On the other hand, the `created_time` field would be useful for comparison.